# Installing ubuntu on secondary hard drive to be built into another device

Tags: grub2, system-installation, hard-drive

Here's the story: I have a quite old laptop with a broken dvd drive, a broken harddisk and no possibility to boot from usb. My idea was to build a harddisk as secondary drive into my pc (which already runs with ubuntu) and install ubuntu (or xubuntu or some other derivate with modest requirements) on it. After that I would integrate that harddisk in the old laptop.

My question is, how to install ubuntu on that drive without corrupting the existing boot loader, grub, whatever on the pc. Should that be installed using a live system or can it be done from the running system? Are there any pitfalls I have to deal with when I install ubuntu via another system than that it should work with afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe should be a comment rather than an answer, but I don't have enough rep to comment.

Have you considered a netboot install?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

Read the docs naturally, but I'm pretty sure this wouldn't overwrite GRUB during the install.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do that by removing the existing hard drive from the working computer. Hook the spare drive up to the good computer as the *only* drive during the installation. That way you wouldn't have to worry about overwriting the existing bootloader as it wouldn't even be attached to the computer during installation. When the installation is done, swap the drives and you should be good to go. I have moved hard drives with Ubuntu from computer to computer with no problems in the past as Ubuntu is very versatile in that aspect.